# TableLayout vertical scrollbar pointing top most Row

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating controls dynamically and adding to the `tablelayout`. When the controls go over the size of the table it is showing a vertical scroll bar, which is fine..

But the scroll bar is pointing to the top. I want to point the scrollbar always down, then I can see the newly added controls..

Like:

[image]

[image]